# Arduino to PC Bluetooth Communication

Tags: c#, android, python, c++, bluetooth

I am using PIR motion sensor with Arduino Bluno (with Bluetooth module). I want to send the the values of motion detected by the sensor from arduino to PC via Bluetooth.

How may i get that on my PC? It can be of C++,C# or even Python.
Shall be thankfull if anyone can help.

Here's my arduino code:

```
int ledPin = 13;                // choose the pin for the LED
int inputPin = 2;               // choose the input pin (for PIR     
int pirState = LOW;
char str1;// we start, assuming no motion detected
int val = 0;
volatile int count =0;// variable for reading the pin status

void setup() {

// pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      // declare LED as output
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(inputPin, INPUT);     // declare sensor as input

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), pin_ISR,FALLING);
}

void pin_ISR() {

 count++;

Serial.write(Serial.print(count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want the pc to directly receive, you could use another arduino to receive an print to the serial monitor.  You could then have a program collect and save what came into the serial monitor.  Just a suggestion.  It may be easier in the end.  Good luck whatever you choose to do.